# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

When I run the dd line, I can successfully see the data, but `$applicatesave->job_post_id =($id);` does not work in line

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'job_post_id' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `job_post_questions` (`question`, `application_id`, `type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (dasdsadas, 10, 2, 2023-04-08 16:56:15, 2023-04-08 16:56:15))
```

```php
public function applicationsave(Request $request, $id)
{
    // dd($id);

    $cv = $request->file('cv'); // Dosya yükleniyor
    $cvName = time() . '_' . $cv->getClientOriginalName(); // Dosya adı oluşturuluyor
    $cv->move(public_path('cv'), $cvName); // Dosya kaydediliyor

    $applicatesave = new applications();
    $applicatesave->name = $request->name;
    $applicatesave->email = $request->email;
    $applicatesave->phone_number = $request->phone_number;
    $applicatesave->city = $request->city;
    $applicatesave->linkedin = $request->linkedin;
    $applicatesave->job_post_id =($id);
    $applicatesave->cv = 'cv/' . $cvName;

    $applicatesave->save();

    foreach($request->question as $key=>$data){
        $question = Job_post_questions::firstOrCreate(
            ['question' =>  $key],
            [
                'application_id' => $applicatesave->id,
                'type' => 2,

                ]
        );

        Answers::create([
            'question_id' => $question->id,
            'answer' => $data,
            'applications_id' => $applicatesave->id
        ]);
    }

    return back();
}
```

I wanted to save the id data in the `job_post_id` column but I am getting an error

Comment: Could you make `dd($id)` and check if it has a value?

Comment: yes ı do dd and i take value

Comment: This error seems to happen when you want to create Job Post Question, and the problem is not with the `id` in the request. The problem is when you save `applicatesave`, you need to `refresh` the model to retrieve the `id` and then use it in `JobPostQuestion` creation. So after saving `$applicatesave` use do `$applicatesave->refresh()`

Answer (score 0):

Because the job_post_id column of job_post_questions table is not nullable and you don't set default value for ir on schema, you have to set value for it when you insert a record to job_post_questions.

1. If you don't use that column, just drop job_post_id column from job_post_questions table
2. If you need to use that column, do:

   ```
    //....
    $question = Job_post_questions::firstOrCreate(
        ['question' =>  $key],
        [
            'application_id' => $applicatesave->id,
            'type' => 2,
            'job_post_id' => $id
        ]
    );
    //....
   ```